# UV absorbance titration to determine binding stoichiometry

Tags: organic-chemistry, stoichiometry, titration, uv-vis-spectroscopy, ligand-field-theory

I previously posted a question but I think I did not explain correctly. I want to construct a Job plot using UV-Vis titration to find binding stoichiometry. I have 20uM of ligand solution and 20uM of DNA solution. Volume of each solution is 800uL. The total concentration of ligand and dsDNA remained unchanged(20uM) during entire titration. Ligand intercalates into dsDNA.

I want to know the protocol to do UV-Vis titration. Like how I should proceed. Do I need to prepare solution of different concentration everytime (for example ligand solution --- 20uM, take UV absorbance,
Now make a complex solution of say 18uM ligand and 2uM dsDNA and so on)

I have no idea what to do.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you want and therefore difficult to provide it. Unless you have troubles with equation y = x / ( 800 - x ). Regarding protocols, it is mixing liquids in desired ratio, waiting for required time if needed and then measuring absorbance.   Then you can interpolate points visually or numerically by 2 lines and taking the intersection as the equivalence point.

Comment: I want to do continuous variation method to construct Job plot.

Comment: As it is about the same thing, with additional info, it should be put in initial question, with a comment if needed.  // So you have 800 uL total for each solution, right? What total volume is needed for measurement?   //  Asking for answers and not providing enough relevant details, purpose, context or background of questions are contradictory decisions.

Comment: I closed previous question as a duplicate. As @Poutnik mentioned, please [edit] your question instead of re-posting it again with more details. This way comments, your editing history and narration are all preserved within one post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can advice only in general methodic, I cannot say what you can afford wrt the particular solutions, regarding their stability and interaction.

If the volume of available solutions **is not** the limiting factor, the easiest way is to prepare extra solution mixture for each measurement.

- Take $x\ \pu{ \mu L}$ of the ligand solution
- Take $a - x\ \pu{\mu L}$ of DNA solution
- It gives $\frac{x}{a-x}$ ligand/DNA ratio.

Then you can measure the series of plot point absorbance vs ligand/DNA ratio.

If the volume of available solutions **is** the limiting factor, you may try the series of incremental additions of the ligand and following measurements.

You would take

- $V_1\ \pu{ \mu L}$ of solution of the prior ratio $r_1$
- add $V_2\ \pu{ \mu L}$ of the ligand solution to get the new ratio:

$$r_2 = \frac{r_1(V_1+V_2) + V_2}{V_1}$$

But there are 2 cons:

- Higher cummulative experimental errors with excessive solution manupulations.
- Possible effects of stability and interaction of incrementally mixed solutions.

When you have measurement done, you can visially or numerically approximate the poins by 2 lines and to take the intersection as the point of equivalence.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So is it same if I want to calculate for DNA/ligand ratio?

Comment: Yes, it is, you would have just mutually switch the relevant parameters.